# Expand collapse resources full calendar scheduler

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I use full calendar scheduler framework and I use resources as projects, so for example resource A is one projects that contains 5 events and events are employers, I use this code to trigger click event on each resource

```
resourceRender: function(resourceObj, labelTds, bodyTds) {
                labelTds.on('click', function(){console.log("click", bodyTds);});

            },
```

and I want to expand and collapse resource on click event, how am I suppose to do that

Answer (score 0):

Add the fc-expander class to the resource cell using the [resourceRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourceRender) callback.

```
resourceRender: function (resource, cellEls, bodyTds) {
                    cellEls.find(".fc-cell-text").addClass("fc-expander");
                }
```